# Should I keep source files in memory while parsing?

Tags: c, parsing

I'm writing the front-end part of an interpreter and I initially disliked the idea of just dumping all the source files into memory and then referencing that text directly. So the tokenizer reads from a char buffers and builds the token stream.

However, I have reached the parsing side of things and it hit me that because I would want to output nice errors and warnings that show the malformed line of source code. I guess I could put column numbers in the tokens, but then by error messages would be like getting directions by telephone: "It's in file X, on line Y, column Z, right next to the curly brace, you know the one. If you hit the semicolon, you've gone to far."

I seem to have put myself into a situation where I want to have my cake and eat it too. I want nice messages, but I don't want to hog memory.

It there something I'm missing? Or is loading the source in memory the way to go?

Comment: We're long past the days where a file the size of an ordinary source code file is expected to be a memory hog.

Comment: There is no defined behavior for errors, so trying to be too informative about what went wrong is for the most part an impossible task. Just do what other parsers do and just point where it is.

Comment: You may also want to look at `mmap`.

Comment: @Havenard Good error handling is what separates good compilers from bad compilers.

Comment: you should take an intro course on compilation, what you need to learn is parsing, to output nice messages there are lots of advanced nontrivial algorithms that guess the good point.  my impression is that you need to start with such a course, for example the book of Dick Grune is a good starting point and Dragon Book is more advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there's an error to report to the user, it hardly matters how long in milliseconds it takes to report it.

I'd keep your tokenized stream in memory to keep your interpreter fast. (Actually, you should switch to a threaded interpreter or even a bad one pass compiler to enhance the execution rate).

When you encounter an error, go to the disk, fetch the line(s) of interest, and show them to the user.    If he doesn't make any errors, this costs you zero.  If he makes a small number of errors, that may be tiny bit inefficient but the user won't know.   If he makes large number of errors, the file content of the files containing errors are going to read by the OS into its local cache, which is likely bigger than your programs anyway, and so access will be more efficient than if you kept the source entirely on the disk.

Comment: You make a good point about repeating errors coming from the same files. Reopening them on a need-to basis seems like the right move. Could you recommend me a good starting point to read on threaded interpreters? (I am currently in the "bad one pass compiler" phase)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code  This is easy to generate from a bad one pass compiler, but is compact and pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

Better idea: `mmap` your sources in the first place, if you can. Fall back to slurping the whole file if you're reading from a pipe or something.

After parsing, you *may* want to call `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)` (but *only* if it was originally `mmap`ed) to advise the kernel to drop it from the cache (but still keep it available for errors) ... but this is probably not necessary, and may even not be a good idea, depending on your compiler design (e.g. are identifiers still pointing, or are they interned to a single, separate, allocation).